# Is this algorithm quadratic or linear?

Tags: algorithm

I have the following algorithm:

```
s=0
for j=1 to n
    k=n
    while k>0
        s++
        k=(int)k/2
    endwhile
endfor
```

For what I have analyzed when:

```
j=1 the while loop executes 1 time
j=2 the while loop executes 2 times
j=3 ...                     2 times
j=4 ...                     3 times
j=5 ...                     3 times
j=6 ...                     3 times
j=7 ...                     3 times
j=8 ...                     4 times
```

So I will have a summation of (n/2)*n of the outer loop, so will this be O(n^2)?

Comment: Neither quadratic or linear!

Comment: It is `O(n.log(n))`

Comment: No, inner loop is log(n), and outer loop n, so O(n.log(n)).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès could you please explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop will be executed *floor(log<sub>2</sub>n)* times, so the total algorithm has *O(n.long(n))* complexity.

You can see that the inner loop is executed this number of times

```
 n    times
-------------
 1      1
 2      2
 4      3
 8      4
16      5
32      6
...    ...
2ⁿ      n+1
```

Take *log<sub>2</sub>()* from both sides of the *equation* and you get:

```
 n     log(n+1)
```

*log(n+1)* is *O(log(n))*.